# When is populated the listview associated to a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have this code inside a ListFragment:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) this.getListView().getChildAt(0);
tv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.OtherColor));
```

I wanted write this code onActivityCreated, but tv is null.

If I write this code inside onListItemClick, it works perfectly.

Is it imposible what I want?

code:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    String[] values = new String[] { getResources().getString(R.string.menu_partida),
              getResources().getString(R.string.menu_acciones),
              getResources().getString(R.string.menu_resultado) };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_menu, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are only draw after all of the "creation" callbacks have executed, there is no callback for this event.  However you can `post()` a Runnable to the UI Handler and achieve the same thing:

```
getListView().post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        TextView tv = (TextView) this.getListView().getChildAt(0);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.OtherColor));
    }
}
```

But really, this change won't do what you expect since the row layouts are recycled in a ListView. (You will see eradict behavior while scrolling.)  You should create a custom Adapter to change the layout for the row at `position 0` *only*.  You might get away with the Runnable since you only have three rows, but the best solution is to extend Adapter.

Comment: Thank you Sam. I think I must find another way to do that